# How do I create a QComboBox delegate that hovers over a QTableView？

Tags: qt

I created a delegate class inherited from QStyledItemDelegate and re-implemented the paint function. QComboBox hovers over QTableView, but QComboBox cannot be expanded.

I'm trying to re-implement the paint function

```
    QString value = index.model()->data(index,Qt::DisplayRole).toString();
    QStyleOptionComboBox socbox;
    socbox.initFrom(cbox);
    socbox.state = option.state;
    socbox.rect = option.rect;
    socbox.currentText = value;
    socbox.editable = false;
    socbox.frame = true;
    socbox.popupRect = QRect(option.rect.x(),option.rect.y(),option.rect.width(),option.rect.width());
    QApplication::style()->drawComplexControl(QStyle::CC_ComboBox,&socbox,painter,cbox);
```

Above is the core code I implemented in the paint function.

The running effect is as follows：
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YHBuZ.gif)

How do I get QComboBox to hover over QTableView and QComboBox to expand and collapse properly？

Answer (score 0):

The logic is very hard to implement at the beginning. You can have a look at the link here: https://forum.qt.io/post/422423
You can combine your code with these.